# Fill data in manually created columns in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a data grid view in my form. I entered the columns in it through "ADD Columns" and the first column is programmed to display a combobox as soon as the user selects the first cell of any row.

Based on the selection made by the user, I want to display the data in the remaining columns. For that I am using following basic query:

```
string sql = "select time, [PARTY NAME], [PARTY NO], DATE from dgvdata where id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

dataadapter.Fill(ds, "dgvdata");

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "dgvdata";
```

This query is working fine, but problem is that it display the data beyond manually created columns. As shown in screenshot:

[image]

My question is: how can I show the data returned from query from column named "TIME" (Blue highlighted).

Thanks in advance ...

EDIT-1 ...

thanks guys , problem solved . now encounters with other issue . I was using

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

method to add new row in the datagridview when user press tab or enter in the last column . but now it giving error of

```
 "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound." .
```

How can I Add new row and one more question , will it show the data in newly created row upon value section in combobox or it will replace the earlier loaded data  . if it replace the data then how to view data on newly created row leaving previous data as it .

Comment: You need to set `DataPropertyName` of the columns to the columns from which you want to display data.

Comment: Also, you must set the DataGrid `AutogenerateColumns` property to false if you have already defined the columns

Comment: @Chetan  , thanks ... problem solved ....